# Labels on Grid lines in HighchartsJS

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts and trying to add labels to the grid lines of a polar chart, however, I can only add labels to the first axis (which is the y-axis in the cartesian coordinate system).

[Polar charts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.polar) are not well covered (as well as labels on grids) in the highcharts docs. My current approach is placing the labels manually on the correct positions, which will get cumbersome due to dynamic number of categories and sizes of my chart. Additionally, exporting the chart will not support labels anymore.

**Background:** Let's assume I am selling tickets for clubbing from Monday to Friday (no weekends, bad choice) for the clubs Green, Black, and Blue. Now, I want to know which club performed best on each day, and also how many tickets are sold in total. Therefore, I'd like to apply different scalings to each axis as attached (manually manipulated). I'm currently normalizing the ticket sales for each day to 0…1 which does the job for comparing each single day, but I can't apply the different labels to the axis.

[image: (manually manipulated) Example of the result]

Comment: How would you know which axis labels relate to which series here? Do you just want each y-axis' labels to appear next to one of the lines from origin to the day label? Do you have code for your example?

Comment: The axis labels don't need to relate to the series (colors), but to the axis (weekdays). Unfortunately, I don't have code for the example above since it's just photoshopped to show what I want to achieve.

The solution could be an options parameter like

```gridLabels: function(value, axis) { return value*scaleFactors[axis]; }```. Also, I am aware it doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you considered using scatter series with disabled markers but enabled dataLabels only? You can then set `enableMouseTracking` to false for that scatter and it will behave like axis labels.

Comment: That's a smart way to look at it. Sounds like the best idea I approached so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to add more panes (with `startAngle` correction) and yAxes with different scales, so dataLabels are showing as in your image.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6b9m7Lvb/

Problem - each yAxis can have only a single pane, each series can have only a single yAxis, so there is one scale for a series - no matter what category.

Another way could be to do the same, but have all yAxes linked to each other, so scale is the same for all. Next it is possible to change axis labels and tooltip display, to match your image.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6b9m7Lvb/1/